# Create a UPnP Control Point in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, upnp

I'm interested in creating a UPnP control point in Silverlight.  To me that implies that I'll need to use COM interop with Microsoft's upnp.dll (and the SL application will have to be out of browser and platform specific).  Is there any source code available in C# that shows how to create a control point with Microsoft's stack?  If there are other options available I'd like to hear about it, from reading around the web it appears the MS stack is buggy.

Answer (score 3):

Here is something I stumbled upon today. Maybe it's still a help.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/upnplib.aspx

A VB.NET example, though no C#, it looks interesting too:
http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=6104&lngWId=10